# How to convert String to BigDecimal without scientific notation

Tags: java

I am trying to convert String value to BigDecimal value.
when i use 0.000001234 I am getting same value in BigDecimal. But, when I use 0.000000123 or 0.000000012 I am getting 1.23E-7 or 1.2E-8.

I need like below,
if input is String = 0.000000123

Then output should be,
BigDecimal = 0.000000123

Please help me

```
import java.math.BigDecimal;

public class DecimalEx {


        public static void main(String args[]){

            String s = "0.000000023";
            BigDecimal big = new BigDecimal(s);         
            System.out.println(big);
        }
}
```

Answer (score 9):

You're converting the `String` to a `BigDecimal` with no problems. The `BigDecimal` value has no notion of whether the value has exponential notation or not... it's just a scaled value.

The problem you're seeing is when you implicitly call [`BigDecimal.toString()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#toString--), which is documented to use exponential notation sometimes:

> If the scale is greater than or equal to zero and the adjusted exponent is greater than or equal to -6, the number will be converted to a character form without using exponential notation.

Instead, you want to use [`BigDecimal.toPlainString()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#toPlainString--):

> Returns a string representation of this BigDecimal without an exponent field.

Just change your last line of code to:

```
System.out.println(big.toPlainString());
```